# Most efficient way to persist XML data in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, persistence

I am loading a large XML file into my ASP.NET application.  I don't want to continue to load the same XML document every time I need the data.  I only want to load it once and persist it throughout the application.

These are my questions:

What is the best and most efficient practice?  My thought is to create a model and referencing the object through the cache.

Comment: Put in application cache with file dependency

Comment: You could save the data using a binary serialization method which would load quicker.  What type object are you loading the xml data into currently?

Comment: @Krishna - Is that thread safe?  Also, is that the preferred practice for  both web forms and MVC?

Comment: @jdweng - I don't have a specific type in mind.  At the moment, I'm concerned about loading and persisting the data and performance.

Comment: With very large files you will get out of memory exception unless you use XmlReader.  Look at my solution on following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274568/how-to-read-an-xml-file-by-using-xmlreader-in-c-sharp

Comment: @jdweng - Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Usually large xml files has an array of one tag that repeats.  So the I like to parse the one element that repeats using xml linq.  Parsing one section of the large xml avoids the memory error.